# Given the set A, would it be correct to say that there are 4 subsets of A that have single element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Given the set $A = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3 \}$, would it be correct to say that there are $4$ subsets of $A$ that have a single element?

---

This is a question from a math book I'm studying. The answer to that question according to this book is that yes, it would be correct to say that there are 4 subsets of A that have a single element. Which would be: {1}, {2}, {3} and {4}.
However, I was in doubt because I thought that the empty set is a subset with a single element of any other set. So wouldn't it be correct to say that there are 5 subsets with a single element for set A or is the book correct?

Comment: What is a "unitary" subset?  Is that different from a "unit" subset?  If you just mean "a set with a single element", then the empty set is not an example as it lacks a single element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "unitary subset" is not standard terminology, so we'll need to know how the source book defines it.

Comment: Is the math book in English, or are you translating from some other language?

Comment: I am really sorry! I translated the question from another language. What I would like to say is "a set with a single element" (I just edited my question).

Comment: @lulu but an empty set doesn't have an empty set as an element?

Comment: The empty set is not an element of itself.  It is a subset of itself, but not an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty set, by definition, has no elements. (So it does not have a single element.)

Comment: Thank you! I thought every set, including the empty set, would have an empty set as an element.

Comment: @LuizSilva If the empty set had the empty set as an element, it wouldn't be empty, would it? $\varnothing$ has no elements. $\{\varnothing\}$ has one element, the empty set. These are different sets. You're probably getting (as lulu comments) with the fact that the empty set is a *subset* of every set.

Comment: Really! Now it's clearer. I understood better thanks to your explanation. Many thanks for your reply!